# WorkManager calls doWork() method more than once when device is Locked

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager, background-service

I am trying to execute a background sync which runs every 15 minutes. Below is the WorkManager initialization for my sync to happen:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest syncRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkerClass.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).addTag("sync").build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("sync", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, syncRequest);
```

But when my device is locked, for some reasons this sync is happening twice until device is unlocked. As soon as device is unlocked and launch the app even then this sync triggers twice, but from next sync it works fine.

Device am using is TC25 Zebra running on Nougat

Dependency that am using in my app.gradle file :

`implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"`

Can anyone suggest what's the best way to avoid duplicate calls.

Comment: Where are you enqueueing your work request?

Comment: Also, WorkManager added a lot of bugfixes on the latest stable releases on the v2.x branch. That requires moving to `androidx`.

Comment: If you don't have particular requirements to use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`, I suggest that you use `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP`, this avoids stopping a possibly already running worker to replace it with a new one.

Comment: I've tried with both KEEP and REPLACE , didn't make a difference. It was triggering twice anyways when device was locked.

Comment: Also, I can't migrate to androidx because my targetSDK version is 26.

Comment: Target SDK v28 is currently a requirement for new apps and will be a requirement from Nov. 1st 2019 for app updates. https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Comment: Yes I know that to migrate  to androidx it requires target SDK = 28. But is there any other way to stop multiple calls .  @pfmaggi

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly handle the `onStopped` callback and cooperatively stop your work. Otherwise you will definitely see multiple instances of your `Worker` running at the same time.

Comment: If its a periodic request then why do I need to stop my work in onStopped method().